# How to make a class in Qt both scriptable and serializable?

Tags: qt, qobject, qtscript, qvariant

I'm trying to write a class with two basic characteristics:

- It needs to be scriptable - the class contains a number of properties and methods decorated with `Q_INVOKABLE` that are exposed to scripts.
- It needs to be serializable so that it can be registered with [`qRegisterMetaTypeStreamOperators()`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qmetatype.html#qRegisterMetaTypeStreamOperators) for storing in `QVariant`s.

As far as I can tell, I need to derive from `QObject` in order to make the class scriptable. However, in order to register the class with `qRegisterMetaTypeStreamOperators()`, it seems like the class needs to have a default copy constructor - something a `QObject`-derived class cannot have.

Is there any way to achieve both goals?

Answer (score 0):

You can have scriptable objects not derived from QObject but it's more work. It's discussed [here](http://harmattan-dev.nokia.com/docs/library/html/qt4/scripting.html#managing-non-qobject-based-objects)